# Is it possible to send data to a specific login-required web service with C# using its defined method without HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, web-services, httprequest, webclient, send

I have access to WSDL file of a specific web service that contains a SendData method - basically I specify the TimeStamp and Value to be send. I uploaded the WSDL file to my project in Visual Studio 2019 as a connected service (Add->Connected Service->Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider->Browse->I added location of the WSDL file and specified the service that included SendData method). After that I created a new client:

```
ServiceSoapClient client = new ServiceSoapClient(ServiceSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration.ServiceSoap);
```

added credentials (the web service requires login):

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test"; client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "test";
```

created a new variable Data that contains TimeStamp and Value (in a specific format required by the method).

After that I invoked the method:

```
client.SendData(Data);
```

but it doesn't work. There are no errors or exceptions thrown, but the Data is not visible on the web service (the web service also has a GUI). I started to wonder if it is possible to send data to a web service in such a way or is it maybe necessary to create an xml file with a request and use HttpWebRequest?

Perhaps someone could help me figure out what is wrong, is there a way to check, what is going on during compilation? Unfortunately, I cannot include the URI or WSDL file, but hopefully my description of the issue will be sufficient. Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: There are too many variables here to make your question reasonably answerable.  The data is getting lost somewhere along the way.  You need to figure out where.  I would start by using Wireshark or Telerik Fiddler to see if your SendData call is actually transmitting anything.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I will download both and try to find out.

Comment: Actually your suggestion was really helpful. I downloaded Fiddler to find out if the SendData call is transmitting anything and unfortunately it is not. I'm not sure what the problem is, the method SendData (SendDataAsync, to be precise) is available after creating the proxy and I would understand receiving an error message from the web service, but there is nothing. Would you have any suggestions on how to proceed to find potential mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, with the suggestion from Robert Harvey (thank you once again) and some trial and error I managed to solve my problem. Hopefully my answer will be useful to someone with the similar issue.

I found out that in some cases WCF web service's calls are not visible in Fiddler. In my case it was due to some packages not being up-to-date. These out-of-date packages were added automatically after connecting the web service via Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider.

System.ServiceModel.Duplex/Http/NetTcp/Security all were installed in version 4.4 instead of 4.7. I updated them using Project->Manage NuGet Packages and now my requests are visible in Fiddler and I managed to verify that the way I used my method was correct, but the access to the web service (with the ability to save data) is currently limited, that is why the result was not visible directly on the web service (in the GUI).